# Will lubuntu remind me to upgrade after 3 years?

Tags: lubuntu

Will lubuntu remind me to upgrade after 3 years or will it happen after 5 years ?

Comment: Ubuntu usually reminds as soon as a new version is released depending upon the preferences (LTS or non LTS). For LTS releases, it reminds after first point release like 18.04.1 which is usually released in July

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 is LTS for three years only.

Comment: If you miss the end of life announcement then it simply won't upgrade any longer. There are usually plenty of announcements on the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) From the accepted answer: *Security and maintenance updates will be provided for Lubuntu LTS releases for 3 years.*

Comment: fyi:  Kulfy's comment applies to all flavors of Ubuntu including Lubuntu.  If you install 18.04 LTS, you'll get the option to upgrade to 20.04 LTS a few days after the release of 20.04.1.  Lubuntu's unique packages only come with 3 years of support for LTS releases (9 months regular releases); though the packages that are shared with Ubuntu will still receive upgrades for a further two years but you should upgrade rather than having only part of your system using supported packages.

Answer (score 0):

In 'software and updates' there is a section named 'updates', at the bottom there is a section where you choose if you want to be reminded or not.  At least in Ubuntu, I think Lubuntu has something similar.  Think the default setting is to be reminded though.